# Adding Play! Framework play start and stop to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently using Eclipse for a project and also the Play! Framework. I wanted to add buttons to this dropdown in Eclipse

[image]

that say :

Play Start myfile1

play stop myfile1

play start myfile2

play stop myfile2

I have it for one project but not a new project I am starting. I'm not setting them up right because i keep getting an error:
'Launching play1 start filename' has encountered a problem.

Exception occurred executing command line.

I don't know how I'm messing it up. Something to do with where the locations I'm setting? Here is the first screen in configurations that i am trying and it isn't working. 
[image]
Help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to show us what you have set up in the external tools configuration for these commands.

Comment: @greg-449, I have added a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I have the solution.

1) Click on the dropdown play button with briefcase

2) click External Tools Configurations.

- New Configuration underneath "Program"

  Name it. i.e.   play start *filename*

  Location: ${play}

  click Variables

  Edit Variables

  New Variable

  Variable Name: play

  Value: D:\play-1.2.5\play.bat    (or wherever you have your play.bat
  file.)

  Ok, Ok, ok, go back to main External Tools Configurations screen.

Working Directory: ${workspace_loc}

Arguments:  start *filename*

Switch tab to "Common" tab.

Click the radial button for Shared file and go to your app file:

i.e.  \filename

Check "External Tools"

Every other default should be fine. Click apply and it should start your play application. Do the same for "stop" but replace "start" with "stop."

Answer (score 0):

I generally have Play running in a separate console window.  Do play start and then play run.  Leave it running all all. The play app is now available at localhost:9000.  Then you can start Eclipse and start coding.  Play will re-compile and reload the app on-the-fly.  Generally you don't have to stop play (type ctrl-D) unless you make a substantial change.

Comment: yeah that's how I've been doing it too, It's just a lot more convenient for me to have buttons since I have to switch between workspaces frequently and have to use a different version of play for each workspace...that's why I really wanted to figure out how to properly add the buttons